# How to display a custom taxonomy without a link?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, template-tags

I need to display the name of a custom taxonomy term in a page template, and I've tried with the following line:

```
<h2><?php the_terms( 0, 'my_category'); ?></h2>
```

This correctly retrieves the taxonomy and displays the desired term, but it also adds a link to that term archive page.

I'd like to display only a simple text, with no link at all.

How should I modify this?

---

To give more context:

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
    'tax_query' => array(
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'my_category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'my_term',
         ),
    ),
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?> 

<div>

    <h2><?php the_terms( 0, 'my_category'); ?></h2>

</div>

<?php

while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
   $my_query->the_post(); 

?>

<div>

    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

    <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>

</div>


<?php

endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the raw list of terms attached to a post with the [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) function. You can then use this to output their names without a link:

```
$my_categories = get_the_terms( null, 'my_category' );

if ( is_array( $my_categories ) ) {
    foreach ( $my_categories as $my_category ) {
        echo $my_category->name;
    }
}
```

To account for the possibility of multiple terms, you probably want to output the list of names separated by commas, in which case you could put the names into an array and `implode()` them:

```
$my_categories  = get_the_terms( null, 'my_category' );

if ( is_array( $my_categories ) ) {
    $category_names = wp_list_pluck( $my_categories, 'name' );

    echo implode( ', ', $category_names );
}
```

---

*I'll leave the above, even though it turns out it's not relevant to OP, because it's still the correct answer to the original question as it appeared.*

In regards to the updated question, if you want to output the name of a term given a specific slug, you need to retrieve that term with `get_term_by()` and then output it by echoing the `name` property of the resulting object.

```
<?php 

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
    'tax_query' => array(
         array(
            'taxonomy' => 'my_category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'my_term',
         ),
    ),
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$term = get_term_by( 'slug', 'my_term', 'my_category' );
?> 

<div>

    <h2><?php echo $term->name; ?></h2>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, there isn't the possibility for multiple terms in this case; I'm trying with `<h2><?php echo get_the_terms( 0, 'my_category')->name; ?></h2>`, but I'm getting this error `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in {source file}`

Comment: Even if there's only 1 term, `get_the_terms()` still returns an array.

Comment: I've tried both of your solutions and they are not working for me. In both cases I get an `invalid argument` error.

Comment: Are you substituting `my_category` for your actual taxonomy name?

Comment: Yes I wrote `my_category` here just to generalize, in my template file I'm actually using the real name.

Comment: Ok, so double checking the docs and it looks like `get_the_terms()` returns `false` if there are no terms set, which is (for some reason) different to `get_terms()`, which returns an empty array. So all you need to do is check if `$my_categories` is an array first. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've edited my question to give more context; all of this is related to a query which already filtered posts belonging to a single category term.

Comment: Ok, because that's a completely different question, and `the_terms()` was being used incorrectly to start with. Why aren't you just using the archive?

Comment: I need to create a page with a restaurant menu; I have a "Dish" CPT with an associated "Dish Category" taxonomy, and both of these should not behave like regular posts (no archive, no index, no single page and URL for each item), they are intended to be only displayed as raw html inside a single "menu" page. The "Dishes" are sorted for categories like "First", "Sides", and the likes.

Comment: In your template, is `my_term` being populated dynamically, or have you hard-coded in a query for each term?

Comment: I have three sections in my page, each with its own different query; they all filter for posts belonging to `my_category`, the first query looks for `my_term_1`, the second for `my_term_3`, the third for `my_term_3`

Comment: `the_terms( )` basically does what I need, it just adds a link that I don't need

Comment: No it doesn't. It's just a coincidence that it's currently working. `the_terms()` is for displaying any terms _that are attached to the current post_. In your use case there is no 'current post', because you're using the function outside of the loop. See my updated answer.

Comment: It worked now, thank you for helping me and for your patience. Have a nice day!